# Cloudformation SQS Policy for S3 events

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create a policy for an SQS queue which would allow any S3 bucket to send events to the queue. I don't seem to be able to do this for a specific S3 queue because I end up with circular dependencies.

I've created a cloudformation template which will create the queue and policy, but when I try and manually setup the S3 bucket to send the events I get a message saying

> Permissions on the destination queue do not allow S3 to publish
>   notifications from this bucket

The template section that I'm using to create the policy is:

```
    "SQSNotifcationFromS3" : {
        "Type" :        "AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy",
        "DependsOn" : "S3Notifications",
        "Properties" : {
            "PolicyDocument" : {
                "Version": "2012-10-17",
                "Id": "SQSIDsimon",
                "Statement": [
                    {
                        "Sid": "example-statement-ID",
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Principal": {
                            "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
                            },
                        "Action": "SQS:*",
                        "Resource": { "Ref" : "S3Notifications"}
                    }
                ]                  
            },
            "Queues" :      [ { "Ref" : "S3Queue" } ]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the end, I found a solution for this - I set the permissions on the SQS so that any S3 bucket could add events to the queue:

```
    "S3EventQueuePolicy" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy",
        "DependsOn" : [ "S3EventQueue" ],
        "Properties" : {
            "PolicyDocument" : {
                "Id": "SQSPolicy",
                "Statement": [
                    {
                        "Sid": "SQSEventPolicy",
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Principal": "*",
                        "Action": "SQS:*",
                        "Resource": "*",
                        "Condition": {
                            "ArnLike": {
                                "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Queues" : [ { "Ref" : "S3EventQueue"} ]
        }            
    },
```

Comment: DependsOn is redundant here, a `Ref` to `S3EventQueue` already establishes a dependency.  You might want to scope that down to a particular bucket ARN - you probalby don't want just _any_ bucket writing to your queue :P

Comment: actually, there's a better example here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ways-to-add-notification-config-to-bucket.html

Answer (score 0):

In the AWS console, did you confirm that the queue has successfully granted permissions to the s3 bucket?  In SQS, select the queue and look at the permissions tab.

Looking at your template snippet above, I'm not sure what "S3Notifications" points to but I'll assume it's the S3 bucket.  The SQS policy document "Resource" should be the ARN of the S3 bucket.  The "Ref" function on an S3 bucket has a Reference Value of "Name".  You need ARN I believe.

See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/SQSExamples.html

and: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html