# CloudFormation S3 NotificationConfiguration to SQS

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs, serverless-framework

I'm new to CloudFormation and currently trying to send a ***S3:ObjectCreated*** to a specific ***SQS Queue***.

The setup is in the Serverless Framework with Resources defined in  CloudFormation. The problem is with the ***NotificationConfiguration*** with a ***QueueConfigurations*** that keeps giving error after error.

The syntax below seems to be correct when looking at the CloudFormation Designer online:

```
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - s3:ListBucket
      Resource:
        Fn::Join:
          - ""
          - - "arn:aws:s3:::"
            - Ref: LabelBucket

    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - s3:GetObject
        - s3:PutObject
      Resource:
        Fn::Join:
          - ""
          - - "arn:aws:s3:::"
            - Ref: LabelBucket
            - "/*"

    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - SQS:SendMessage
      Resource:
        Fn::Join:
          - ""
          - - "arn:aws:s3:::"
            - Ref: LabelBucket

resources:
  Resources:
    LabelRequestQueue:
      Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
      Properties:
        QueueName: label-generate-request

    LabelResponseQueue:
      Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
      Properties:
        QueueName: label-generate-response

    LabelBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      DependsOn:
          - LabelResponseQueue
      Properties:
        BucketName: generation-bucket
        NotificationConfiguration:
          QueueConfigurations:
            - Event: 's3:ObjectCreated:Put'
              Queue: 'arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-1:539106611526:label-generate-response'
```

The exact error for this resource is:

```
An error occurred: CarrierLabelBucket - Unable to validate the following destination configurations (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument; Request ID: 12A3D93761EFFEAD; S3 Extended Request ID: Zfk2XKEKHhqtafaiFvrcpzyO8nHB6qOJs4gqJXpkOyhxSMgDTsUzZ0lQnYIrTEr2SVHhgMHw0ds=).
```

Comment: Unfortunately, after almost 5 years (at least) since the first mention of this problem, the bug still exists. In my case, I can not even add notification after I've created a bucket - even with AWS console - I still get the same error in console UI.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have followed the instructions on the AWS docs to create the SNS topic first in a different deployment. You can find my working application config here:

### 1. SNS deploy

https://github.com/drissamri/serverless-architecture/blob/master/infrastructure/serverless.yml

### 2. App deploy (S3 notifications)

https://github.com/drissamri/serverless-architecture/blob/master/application/serverless.yml

If you are using Serverless Framework you can also use plugins that hide all the necessary configuration with a simplified config like https://www.npmjs.com/package/@agiledigital/serverless-sns-sqs-lambda

Answer (score 3):

Last answer by Nick is actually the correct one.

If - and when - you set up your resources S3 Bucket + SQS Queue + Policy it will work.

I did it like:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    MyBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: ${self:custom.settings.s3_bucket}
        NotificationConfiguration:
          QueueConfigurations:
            - Event: s3:ObjectCreated:Put
              Queue: "arn:aws:sqs:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:${self:custom.settings.transmit_queue}"
      DependsOn : SQSQueuePolicy

    TransmitQueue:
      Type: "AWS::SQS::Queue"
      Properties:
        QueueName: ${self:custom.settings.transmit_queue}

    SQSQueuePolicy:
      Type: AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy
      Properties:
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                AWS: "*"
              Action: SQS:SendMessage
              Resource: "*"
              Condition:
                ArnLike:
                  aws:SourceArn: "arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.settings.s3_bucket}"
        Queues:
          - Ref: TransmitQueue
```

Finding this out might take you some time.
Ask me how I know.

Comment: I have tried this approach to a 'T.'  I've got a policy, an SQS queue, and a Bucket, where the bucket depends on the policy, all deployed as part of a SAM deployment--no dice.  I am starting to wonder if the SAM differences might have an issue that regular cloud formation does not.  Any ideas or thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a SQS policy to your queue before you can add the S3 SQS event.

[Cloudformation SQS Policy for S3 events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39122179/cloudformation-sqs-policy-for-s3-events)

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `s3:CreatedObject:*` See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#notification-how-to-event-types-and-destinations

Comment: That was one of the steps I added this morning, but directly on Put but it is still not working. I've added more of my Serverless.yml file and the updated error. The error seems to point to: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/unable-validate-destination-s3/ but I haven't gotten the first two suggestions there working yet.